# Straight lines and their locus

Tags: linear-algebra

Three straight lines a, b, c intersecting in pairs pass through three given points A, B C respectively. The lines rotate with angular velocity 'Omega' prove that at some moment of time these straight lines pass through a single point.

Comment: what have you done??

Comment: I even don't think that the lines will pass through a single point because they are rotating with the same angular velocity no, so how can they meet at a point

Comment: I'm feeling miserable at this this question anyone please say something???

Comment: Are they rotating about the origin?

Comment: No that's not given but still u can assume it

Comment: How are they rotating, then? About some arbitrary point on each respective line, perhaps?